# WebDriverManagerException when using WebDriverManager for selenium

Tags: webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

I am using WebDriverManager api to initiate browser. I am using the following code to connect to chrome browser.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()
```

Exception is:

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:117)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:490)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:277)



Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:74)
at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)
at org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(SSLContextBuilder.java:201)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:99)
```

Anyone has any idea about this.

WebDriverManager version 4.0.0
ChromeBrowser 83
selenium version : 3.14.0